# JPA relationship possibility

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following JPA entities

Module class with the following attributes

- Identifier
- String name
- String code
- Person manager

Person class with the following attributes

- Identifier
- String name
- String title
- Person supervisor
- Module module

Now I need to create the following relationships for Person

- A many-to-one relationship to its supervising person
- A many-to-one relationship to its module

I have no idea how to create the relationships in its own class (Person -> Person).

Any suggestions would be welcome.  Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it exactly as if you had two entities of different classes:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @ManyToOne
    Person supervisor;
    ...
}
```

If you want it bidirectional, then you also do it exactly as if you had two entities of different classes:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @ManyToOne
    Person supervisor;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "supervisor")
    Set<Person> supervised;
}
```

Comment: Normally you place a @ManyToOne on the on end and a @OneToMany(mappedby= .....) on the other end. That's why I didn't see how to do this.  So this is enough to make the relationship ...?!

Comment: Thx ... now I understand the solution for the biderectinal association.